# How do I earn reputation points on Superuser?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users, users

I am new here.

I am trying to thank (ie: vote up) or comment on existing questions/answers. But those activities all seem to require points.

Ok - I need points... but all the activities to get points require existing points. Except - it seems - asking a question.

I have no technical questions - pretty much all of what I wanted to ask is already answered here (a good thing!).

I've read the help info and I have searched for "how to get points?" = no results! ... basically my only approach is to post questions.

A catch 22?

Comment: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Thanks David I read that - but it doesn't answer my question. All the items mentioned require that I must first have posted a question.

Comment: No, you generally get rep faster by providing good answers to other people's questions.

Comment: @KimRowden - You can asked questions without having any reptuation.  If you need to submit a screenshot with your question just provide the url.  Eventually somebody with edit priviliages will add the image to your question.  You can also answer other people's questions without the need of any reputation.  Just be sure you actually answer the question that was asked and not some other question that wasn't.

Comment: I'm also confused about why you feel that you need points. Answer questions well and you will get rep.

Comment: @EBGreen - read my question carefully.  I need points to be able to comment on other's questions and answers and to vote up/don an existing discussion  (at least I did when this discussion was in the main list).  As I have already said in my original question: I wasn't looking to post, or answer, questions.

Comment: The purpose of the site is to post questions and get answers. Period. That is the best way to get rep. Period.

Comment: Nearly 9 years later OPs account still has only 1 point. Something the SU community does that is sometimes not appreciated is answer the question BEHIND the question. This is a good thing, but for many reasons, some good, some less so, some people don't recognize the reason for this, don't see the errors in their own assumptions causing them to have passed by the real question, and thus not recognizing the benefit or validity of the information they are given. This question and thread seems a particularly clear example of this, I think.

Answer (score 10):

First I'll answer your question.

1. Most questions do not require you to have points to answer. Some (protected questions) do, but many allow you to answer now. So find some questions that you know the answer to and help some people out (each upvote is worth 10 points)!
2. Ask good questions. If you ask questions that people think are worth their time, they'll often vote up the question (each vote worth 5 points)!
3. Choose the answer to the questions you ask that best works for you. This only provides 2 points.
4. And as overlooked by myself and pointed out by fixer1234, you can edit other users questions and answers. An approved edit nets you 2 points.

It doesn't take all that many good questions or good answers to gain access to the important functions of the site. Go out and conquer!

**However,** you should note that this particular question *probably* should have been asked on the meta portion of the site. So expect this question to be moved and/or deleted.

In the future, ask questions about the function of Superuser on the Meta portion.

Comment: I'll add another source: propose edits to improve exisitng questions and answers. For many users, English is not their first language (or increasingly, texting is). Many posts can be improved (typos, grammar, punctuation, spelling, capitalization, minor rewording for clarity, add reference links, etc.). As a new user, your edits will need to be approved, but improvements normally are, especially if you're thorough. Easy source: run a search for words generally considered inappropriate for polite company and clean up the language. It's 2 points per accepted edit and they take very little time.

Comment: Can under 10 reputation users edit?

Comment: I believe even unregistered users can propose edits.

Comment: `this particular question probably should have been asked on the meta` - which requires 5 points...

Comment: People - why don't you read my question before jumping in with unrelated answers?!?    I mentioned that COMMENTING on something requires points -  and I don't have points!    I expressly said I WASN'T looking to post a question or answer a question. I'm amazed at the level of misunderstanding on this ...!

Comment: I should add that I CAN'T vote down Matt's answer for his being completely off topic - or his not reading the question poperly!  - why? - because it requires 125 points!  How's that for a great way to promote inaccurate answers!

Comment: @kimRowden, You asked how to gain points in order to comment (and vote up). You need 50 points to comment. fixer1234 and myself answered your question. Meaning: we told you how to get points. You need to answer and ask questions, propose edits, award best answers, etc. in order to gain enough points to comment. You CANNOT comment without first doing the activities suggested above, as these activities are reserved for members who have basically "proved themselves" as valuable to the community. I hope this clears up why you received the answers you did.